# Having trouble with constructors and the deque class

Tags: data-structure, snake

I've recently been trying to make a better version of my previous remake of the classic snake game by implementing data encapsulation and abstraction. I also decided to replace my horrible choice of a linked list for holding the snake's tail co-ordinates with the more sensible choice of a deque. Since I am a beginner and I have honestly no clue what is going on *(I'd be worried if I did know what I was doing)*, I would appreciate some assistance with helping me understand what is wrong with my usage of the deque and how I can fix it.

From what I can gather I believe it has something to do with improper usage of constructors, yet I still have not fully grasped the concept of constructors to be able to properly debug it.

## SnakePart.h

```
#ifndef SNAKEPART_H_
#define SNAKEPART_H_

#include <deque>

class SnakePart {
public:
    void advance(int x, int y, bool loose_tail = true);
};

extern std::deque<SnakePart> parts;


#endif /* SNAKEPART_H_ */
```

## SnakePart.cpp

```
#include "SnakePart.h"

void SnakePart::advance(int x, int y, bool loose_tail) {
        std::deque<SnakePart> parts;
        parts.emplace_front(x, y);

        if(loose_tail)
            parts.pop_back();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not referencing the right `parts` instance. When you do `std::deque<SnakePart> parts;` in `SnakePart::advance` you're creating a new instance of the `deque`. The **export**ed `deque` you declare in the header file isn't used at all.

You might want to consider the `advance` being part of the `Snake` instead of the `SnakePart`;

**Snake.h**

```
#ifndef SNAKE_H_
#define SNAKE_H_

#include<deque>
#include"SnakePart.h"

class Snake
{
private: 
    std::deque<SnakePart> parts;
public:
    Snake(int startX, int startY); 
    void advance(int x, int y, bool loose_tail = true);
};

#endif SNAKE_H_
```

**Snake.cpp**

```
#include "Snake.h"

Snake::Snake(int startX, int startY) {
    advance(startX, startY, false);
}

void Snake::advance(int x, int y, bool loose_tail) {
    parts.push_front(SnakePart(x, y));
    if (loose_tail)
        parts.pop_back();
}
```

**SnakePart.h**

```
#ifndef SNAKEPART_H_
#define SNAKEPART_H_

class SnakePart
{
public:
    const int x;
    const int y;
    SnakePart(int x, int y);
};

#endif SNAKEPART_H_
```

**SnakePart.cpp**

```
#include "SnakePart.h"

SnakePart::SnakePart(int px, int py)
    : x(px), y(py) {
}
```

That way the `SnakePart` represents only a part of the snake, and there's no actions on it. The `Snake` on the other hand is a list of parts, and it can grow by calling `advance`.